# tel: URI support in Freeswitch(for outgoing calls)

Tags: asterisk, gateway, voip, sip, freeswitch

I have integrated a Freeswitch instance with an external SIP server and calls are working without any issues. But now I need to change the SIP server which only supports tel: URI.

In the case of incoming calls, Freeswitch is able to identify the number through ^(+999)?(\d{10})$ regular expression. But in outgoing calls, I am unable to send tel: instead of sip: URI due to which SIPGW is rejecting the calls.

Is there any way to force the Freeswitch to use tel: URI in the outgoing calls? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FreeSwitch has no URI support:

https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/src/mod/endpoints/mod_sofia/sofia_glue.c#L1394